# How to prevent distortion of code window in gdb -tui? Debugging commands scroll up and break graphics

Tags: debugging, gdb, command-line-interface

I just started using gdb, so gdb -tui helps visualize process.

However when gdb commands rise up they push window with source code so everything becomes broken.

I set variable to TERM=xterm-256color
as some suggest and this didn't help.

Same behavior for st alacritty and even tty.

[image: Broken source code screen]

Comment: You can refresh the screen with `ctrl-L`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found how to prevent graphics distortion in gdb -tui.
But there are better tools to archive same goal.
Probably -tui option exists only for limited cases when better options are not available due to limitations of installed software.

Using vim with Termdebug lets view code during debug as gdb -tui mode does but without graphics break.
enable termdebug

```
:packadd termdebug
```

start termdebug

```
:Termdebug
```

You can press control_l in gdb -tui to refresh screen. But adding additional key combination after every command is obviously inconvenient.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `ctrl/cmd + L` to refresh your TUl;however, please be aware that the output of your code, such as printf statements, will be lost along with any distortion.

> highly recommend an enhanced interface plugin -- [gdb-dashboard](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard)

Answer (score -1):

Faced the same issue. Using the following command helped.

```
ref
```

This should resolve the graphics issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).